# join tables if condition satisfies

Tags: python, mysql

I have two tables 'A' and 'B'.I need to join two tables when `a1/a2` and `v1` are same,then it should take the respective data as explained below.

```
A

id a1   a2     a3   
1  hi   hello  we
2  see  when   tree
3  bee  animal fly

B
no. v1   v2       
1   bee  null
2   when  null
```

The expected output: Here,when it finds any data `a1/a2` in A with that of v1 in B ,when both are similar then it should get the respective data from `a1/a2` to v2

```
B
no. v1   v2       
1   bee  fly
2   see  tree
```

I have a code which can check for similarity only for one field not for checking both the fields and obtain the result.

My code:

```
import MySQLdb
import os
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="mysql", # your password
                          db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(" SELECT B.NO, B.v1 AS V1, A.a2 AS V2
 FROM A INNER JOIN B
 WHERE A.a1 = B.v1")
db.commit()
```

Please help me to rectify my code!

Answer (score 1):

I guess.. as you want to get the results if either of the columns a1 or a2 in Table A matches with that of column v1 you can simple change the query to as follows:

```
SELECT B.NO, B.v1 AS V1, A.a2 AS V2 FROM A INNER JOIN B WHERE A.a1 = B.v1 OR A.a2 = B.v1
```

Maybe, you can also try using simple JOIN instead of INNER JOIN as

```
SELECT B.NO, B.v1 AS V1, A.a2 AS V2 FROM A JOIN B WHERE A.a1 = B.v1 OR A.a2 = B.v1
```

Comment: NOTE: the removal `INNER` keyword makes no difference in MySQL. In MySQL, `JOIN`, `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN` are all synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's only a couple changes that are needed. It looks like you want a predicate that matches **`v1`** to *either* **`a1`** *or* **`a2`**. That could be accomplished with a predicate like this (as an example):

```
 WHERE B.v1 IN (A.a1,A.a2)
```

The other change would be to return **`A.a3`** rather than **`A.a2`**, that's just change to the column reference in the SELECT list.

Actually, it looks a little more complicated than that. From the example output, it looks like you want to return **`A.a1`** rather than **`B.v1`**.

---

(My personal preference would be to move the predicate from a `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the JOIN. I'd also prefer to omit the `INNER` keyword. But those two changes don't actually effect the query.)

```
  SELECT B.NO
       , A.a1 AS V1
       , A.a3 AS V2
    FROM A
    JOIN B
      ON B.v1 IN (A.a1,A.a2)
```